# What kind of overhead occurs in Bytebuddy's Advice operation?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

With Bytebuddy's Advice, I want to know what the overhead difference is compared to MethodDelegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real performance difference. By default, advice inlines its code while method delegation invokes a different method. This has more to do with code visibility then with performance what the JIT normally figures out just fine.